# Show / hide text on click multiple IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to  show/hide toggle the text shown on a project I'm working on when I click on the title.   i have managed to show the content when I click on the titles but I am not able to hide the content I do not need to display at the time.   The idea is that if I click on title 1, the content in div id="content1" shows.  When I click on title2, only div with id=content2 shows etc.

Thank you all in advance,

Jquery link: https://jsfiddle.net/dt32wshj/3/

```
   <div class="wrap">
   <h1 class="showcontent" id="1">Text 1</h1>
    <div class="content" id="content1">
      <h3 id="sub1">Sub 1.1</h3>
        <div class="sub" id="Xsub1"><p>Para 1.1</p></div>
      <h3 id="sub2">Sub 1.2</h3>
        <div class="sub" id="Xsub2"><p>Para 1.2</p></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <h1 class="showcontent" id="2">Title 2</h1>
    <div class="content" id="content2">
      <h3 id="sub3">Sub 2.1</h3>
        <div class="sub" id="Xsub3"><p>Para 2.1</p></div>
      <h3 id="sub4">Sub 2.2</h3>
        <div class="sub" id="Xsub4"><p>Para 2.2</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <h1 class="showcontent" id="3">Title 3</h1>
  <div class="content" id="content3">
  <h3 id="sub5">Sub 3.1</h3>
  <div class="sub" id="Xsub5"><p>Para 3.1</p></div>
  <h3 id="sub6">Sub 3.2</h3>
  <div class="sub" id="Xsub6"><p>Para 3.2</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*JQuery*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".showcontent").click(function () {
         var name = $(this).attr('id');
          $("#content" + name).fadeIn(1000);
            });    
                 $(".content h3").click(function () {
           var sub = $(this).attr('id');
          $("#X" + sub).slideDown(500);
            });

});
```

Answer (score 4):

The idea is that before you show the current content, you must hide all other content

and you can do this without using ids especially if you have a large content, using classes is more appropriate

the same thing applies to the inner content

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".showcontent").click(function() {
    $(".content").hide();
    $(this).next(".content").fadeIn(1000);
  });
  $(".content h3").click(function() {
     $(".sub").slideUp(500);
    $(this).next(".sub").slideDown(500);
  });

});
```

```css
.sub {
  display: none;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}

h1 {
  cursor: pointer;
}

h1:hover {
  color: blue;
}

h3 {
  cursor: pointer;
}

h3:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <h1 class="showcontent" id="1">Text 1</h1>
  <div class="content" id="content1">
    <h3 id="sub1">Sub 1.1</h3>
    <div class="sub" id="Xsub1">
      <p>Para 1.1</p>
    </div>
    <h3 id="sub2">Sub 1.2</h3>
    <div class="sub" id="Xsub2">
      <p>Para 1.2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <h1 class="showcontent" id="2">Title 2</h1>
  <div class="content" id="content2">
    <h3 id="sub3">Sub 2.1</h3>
    <div class="sub" id="Xsub3">
      <p>Para 2.1</p>
    </div>
    <h3 id="sub4">Sub 2.2</h3>
    <div class="sub" id="Xsub4">
      <p>Para 2.2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <h1 class="showcontent" id="3">Title 3</h1>
  <div class="content" id="content3">
    <h3 id="sub5">Sub 3.1</h3>
    <div class="sub" id="Xsub5">
      <p>Para 3.1</p>
    </div>
    <h3 id="sub6">Sub 3.2</h3>
    <div class="sub" id="Xsub6">
      <p>Para 3.2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this in only javascript by just hiding the relevant classes on click, then revealing just the one clicked:

(You can use .fadeout rather than .hide, depending on your preference)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".showcontent").click(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".content").hide();
    $("#content" + name).fadeIn(1000);
  });

  $(".content h3").click(function() {
    var sub = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".sub").hide();
    $("#X" + sub).slideDown(500);
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks :) this is what i needed

Answer (score 2):

Plenty of ways you can achieve this. One is to save the currently open id in a var, and close it when it's time to open a different div:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

           //hide all content
          $("[id^=content]").hide();
          
          var currentShown = -1;

          $(".showcontent").click(function () {
           var name = $(this).attr('id');
           if (currentShown == name) return;
          //hide currently shown
          $("#content" + currentShown).fadeOut(1000);
          $("#content" + name).fadeIn(1000);
          currentShown = name;
         });
          
          
          $(".content h3").click(function () {
           var sub = $(this).attr('id');
          $("#X" + sub).slideDown(500);
            });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
   <h1 class="showcontent" id="1">Text 1</h1>
    <div class="content" id="content1">
      <h3 id="sub1">Sub 1.1</h3>
        <div class="sub" id="Xsub1"><p>Para 1.1</p></div>
      <h3 id="sub2">Sub 1.2</h3>
        <div class="sub" id="Xsub2"><p>Para 1.2</p></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <h1 class="showcontent" id="2">Title 2</h1>
    <div class="content" id="content2">
      <h3 id="sub3">Sub 2.1</h3>
        <div class="sub" id="Xsub3"><p>Para 2.1</p></div>
      <h3 id="sub4">Sub 2.2</h3>
        <div class="sub" id="Xsub4"><p>Para 2.2</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <h1 class="showcontent" id="3">Title 3</h1>
  <div class="content" id="content3">
  <h3 id="sub5">Sub 3.1</h3>
  <div class="sub" id="Xsub5"><p>Para 3.1</p></div>
  <h3 id="sub6">Sub 3.2</h3>
  <div class="sub" id="Xsub6"><p>Para 3.2</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```